# java random number but the last number is either a 0 or 5 with a minimum of 0 and maximum of 380

Tags: java

I'm stumped with an issue regarding random numbers. I need a way to randomize any number from 0 to 380. but the bigger problem is the last digit has to be either a 0 or 5(I can work with just a 0 if its easier). If you know how to do this please don't hesitate to share! thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please don't hesitate to share that.

Comment: you could loop over 0-380, increment by 5, store the number in a `List` and generate a random number in the range of the size of the `List`. That´s all you need to do to generate such a random number.

Comment: you could randomaze a number between your range, and test if it needs correction afterwards. (e.g. a loop to test if %10 or %5  equals to 0.

Answer (score 7):

Just get a random number from 0 to 76 and multiply that by 5.

Comment: There is beauty in simplicity. I love it!